Can't Load Types for Xamarin Community Toolkit
I am trying to create a Content Page that uses a CameraView
For this, I need the Xamarin Community Toolkit
I have installed the Nuget package for the community toolkit (2.0.6), and am trying to reference it from my XAML page like this:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SharedUi.View.TakePhoto2"
             **xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"**>

When I build, I get this error:
error : Can't load types from xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit
What could be wrong?
